# Redirect to a page after authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

After authenticating a user, how can I redirect them to a dashboard. How would it be customized with information about each user, and not information hard-coded onto a page? How does this relate, if at all, to `getRedirectResult`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll typically [listen to `onAuthStateChanged()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) for that. Whenever the user authentication state changes, your handler will get called and you can act on the new state. E.g.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in so redirect to dashboard
  } else {
    // No user is signed in, so show login page
  }
});
```